# Switching Off Caps Lock Led

Tags: assembly

Using assembly language, how can I switch on and off the Caps Lock LED, with its functionality?

I mean when it is off and on.

Comment: We really need to know platform details to provide a suitable answer, however some might feel inclined to post several examples (which is why I'm not closing this now).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly Keyboard IO Port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434827/assembly-keyboard-io-port)

Comment: `how can I switch on and off the Caps Lock LED, with its functionality`   Just the light or the actual capslock function (uppercase) as well?

Answer (score 2):

In DOS and versions of Windows that support FULL DOS functionality, you can twiddle the bits in the memory location and it will not only switch the state, but will also flip the LED (assuming AT style and newer keyboards).

Reference for more details on the location(s): http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/324/Intro/memory.html